# How to input both character and numeric input vectors in an rcpp fuction?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm fiddling around with the below Rcpp code which works like R's expand.grid(). The goal is to take an unknown quantity of input vectors of any data class and output all combination across the inputs. For example, given `a<-c(1,2)` and `b<-c(3,4,5)`, the function `combine_vectors(list(a,b))` returns:

```
  v1 v2
1  1  3
2  1  4
3  1  5
4  2  3
5  2  4
6  2  5
```

I have it working for numeric input vectors, but for the life of me can't figure out how to handle both strings and numeric vectors. It seems like the crucial change I need to make is to the
`std::vector<std::vector<int>*> combo_vectors;` to be either generic (instead of `<int>`) or to switch based on case. Ideally, I would like to do the type checking in C++.

```
    #include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame combine_vectors(List vectors) {
  int num_vectors = vectors.length();
  
  std::vector<int> indices(num_vectors, 0);
  std::vector<std::vector<int>*> combo_vectors;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < num_vectors; i++) {
    combo_vectors.push_back(new std::vector<int>());
  }
  
  bool done = false;
  while (!done) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_vectors; i++) {
      SEXP vector = vectors[i];
      switch (TYPEOF(vector)) {
        case INTSXP:
          combo_vectors[i]->push_back(IntegerVector(vector)[indices[i]]);
        break;
        case REALSXP:
          combo_vectors[i]->push_back(NumericVector(vector)[indices[i]]);
        break;
        default:
          Rcpp::stop("unsupported vector type");
      }
    }
    
    int i = num_vectors - 1;
    while (i >= 0) {
      indices[i]++;
      if (indices[i] == Rf_length(vectors[i])) {
        indices[i] = 0;
        i--;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    if (i < 0) {
      done = true;
    }
  }
  
  int num_combos = combo_vectors[0]->size();
  List output(num_vectors);
  CharacterVector col_names(num_vectors);
  
  for (int i = 0; i < num_vectors; i++) {
    switch (TYPEOF(vectors[i])) {
      case INTSXP: {
        IntegerVector col(num_combos);
        for (int j = 0; j < num_combos; j++) {
          col[j] = (*combo_vectors[i])[j];
        }
        output[i] = col;
        break;
      }
      case REALSXP: {
        NumericVector col(num_combos);
        for (int j = 0; j < num_combos; j++) {
          col[j] = (*combo_vectors[i])[j];
        }
        output[i] = col;
        break;
      }
      default:
        Rcpp::stop("unsupported vector type");
    }
    
    col_names[i] = std::string("v") + std::to_string(i + 1);
    delete combo_vectors[i];
  }
  
  output.attr("names") = col_names;
  DataFrame df(output);
  
  return df;
}
```

**Edit:** I guess my question is how do I add string vectors? When I added case switching for STRSXP, I get the error "no matching function for call to 'push_back(Rcpp::Vector<16>::Proxy)" Here is the non-working code.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame combine_vectors1(List vectors) {
  int num_vectors = vectors.length();
  
  std::vector<int> indices(num_vectors, 0);
  std::vector <std::vector<int>*>combo_vectors;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < num_vectors; i++) {
    combo_vectors.push_back(new std::vector<int>());
  }
  
  bool done = false;
  while (!done) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_vectors; i++) {
      SEXP vector = vectors[i];
      switch (TYPEOF(vector)) {
      case INTSXP:
        combo_vectors[i]->push_back(IntegerVector(vector)[indices[i]]);
        break;
      case REALSXP:
        combo_vectors[i]->push_back(NumericVector(vector)[indices[i]]);
        break;
      case STRSXP:
        combo_vectors[i]->push_back(CharacterVector(vector)[indices[i]]);
        break;
      default:
        Rcpp::stop("unsupported vector type");
      }
    }
    
    int i = num_vectors - 1;
    while (i >= 0) {
      indices[i]++;
      if (indices[i] == Rf_length(vectors[i])) {
        indices[i] = 0;
        i--;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    if (i < 0) {
      done = true;
    }
  }
  
  int num_combos = combo_vectors[0]->size();
  List output(num_vectors);
  CharacterVector col_names(num_vectors);
  
  for (int i = 0; i < num_vectors; i++) {
    switch (TYPEOF(vectors[i])) {
    case INTSXP: {
      IntegerVector col(num_combos);
      for (int j = 0; j < num_combos; j++) {
        col[j] = (*combo_vectors[i])[j];
      }
      output[i] = col;
      break;
    }
    case REALSXP: {
      NumericVector col(num_combos);
      for (int j = 0; j < num_combos; j++) {
        col[j] = (*combo_vectors[i])[j];
      }
      output[i] = col;
      break;
    }
    case STRSXP: {
      CharacterVector col(num_combos);
      for (int j = 0; j < num_combos; j++) {
        col[j] = (*combo_vectors[i])[j];
      }
      output[i] = col;
      break;
    }
    default:
      Rcpp::stop("unsupported vector type");
    }
    
    col_names[i] = std::string("v") + std::to_string(i + 1);
    delete combo_vectors[i];
  }
  
  output.attr("names") = col_names;
  DataFrame df(output);
  
  return df;
```

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question.  You already switch on type between integer and numeric.  Now it seems you need to do add string vectors.

Comment: I'm not worthy of help from the package creator. <dignified> Bow. Bow. </dignified> I've added the non-working code to the question where I unsuccessfully attempt to switch type to string vectors. I get a compile error when I run `sourceCpp()`, Line 27 says there's no matching pushback.

Comment: You are up against a standard, known and _hard_ problem: we come from a dynamically typed language, now we deal with static types.  It's less forgiving.  But keep looking around, experiment and simplfiy.  I do believe we have several posts that are related at the [Rcpp Gallery](https://gallery.rcpp.org/) -- you can probably even search there for `TYPEOF` or alike.

Comment: Why are you accumulating `combo_vectors` just to then repack it into `output`?

Comment: @DavisHerring A legacy of bloating as I try different things to resolve the types question. I haven't fixed my issue yet, but suspect the answer is with templating.

Comment: Since `output` is type-erased, your whole problem may go away if you target it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know R *or* Rcpp, but it seems simple enough to skip `combo_vectors` and pack sublists (`out1`, which must itself be a generic `List` to be heterogeneous) **directly** into `output`:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame combine_vectors1(List vectors) {
  int num_vectors = vectors.length();

  List output;

  std::vector<int> indices(num_vectors, 0);

  while (true) {
    List out1(num_vectors);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_vectors; i++) {
      SEXP vector = vectors[i];
      switch (TYPEOF(vector)) {
      case INTSXP:
        out1[i] = IntegerVector(vector)[indices[i]];
        break;
      case REALSXP:
        out1[i] = NumericVector(vector)[indices[i]];
        break;
      case STRSXP:
        out1[i] = CharacterVector(vector)[indices[i]];
        break;
      default:
        Rcpp::stop("unsupported vector type");
      }
    }
    output.push_back(out1);

    int i = num_vectors - 1;
    while (i >= 0) {
      indices[i]++;
      if (indices[i] == Rf_length(vectors[i])) {
        indices[i] = 0;
        i--;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    if (i < 0) break;
  }

  CharacterVector col_names(num_vectors);
  for (int i = 0; i < num_vectors; i++) {
    col_names[i] = std::string("v") + std::to_string(i + 1);
  }

  output.attr("names") = col_names;
  DataFrame df(output);

  return df;
}
```

Comment: Your code compiles okay with `Rcpp::sourceCpp()`, but when I tried feeding it a sample list of `lst<- list( y=1:3, z=c(4,5,6,7), x=c("a", "b", "c"))` , to the function as `combine_vectors1(lst)` it gives an error of "Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  unimplemented type 'char' in 'eval'"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with this evening. Mine is not quite and compact as @Davis Herring's answer, but it works now, and I'm posting in case it's helpful to someone else.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List expand(List inputVectors) {
//number of input vectors 
    int num_vectors = inputVectors.length();
//length of each vector  
    IntegerVector vectorLengths(num_vectors);
//names of output colums
    CharacterVector col_names(num_vectors);
// Vector of vector length multiples
    IntegerVector mult_Vector(num_vectors);
//Output 
    List output(num_vectors);
 
//get the input vector lengths and running multiples
 int mult = 1;
 for (int i = 0; i < num_vectors; i++) {
   //column names
   col_names[i] = std::string("v") + std::to_string(i + 1);
   //vector lengths
   switch( TYPEOF(inputVectors[i]) ) { 
   case REALSXP: {
     vectorLengths[i] = ((NumericVector)inputVectors[i]).length();
     }
   case INTSXP: {
    vectorLengths[i] = ((IntegerVector)inputVectors[i]).length();
     }
   case STRSXP: {
     vectorLengths[i] = ((CharacterVector)inputVectors[i]).length();
     }
   }
   //running multiples
   mult_Vector[i]=  vectorLengths[i] * mult;
   mult = mult_Vector[i];
 }

//product of vector lengths  
int product = *(std::end(mult_Vector)-1);
 
//build the expanded combinations  
  int l=0;
  for( List::iterator it = inputVectors.begin(); it != inputVectors.end(); ++it ) {
    switch( TYPEOF(*it) ) {
    case VECSXP: {
      *it = expand(*it);
      break;
    }
    case REALSXP: {
      NumericVector tmp(product);
      
      int combinations = product / vectorLengths[l];
      int mult_length = product / mult_Vector[l];
      int n = 0;
      for (int m = 0; m < combinations; m++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < vectorLengths[l]; k++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < mult_length && n < product; j++) {
            tmp[n] = ((NumericVector)inputVectors[l])[k];
            n++;
          }
        }
      }
      output[l]= tmp;
      l++;
      break;
    }
    case INTSXP: {
      if( Rf_isFactor(*it) ) break; // factors have internal type INTSXP too
      IntegerVector tmp(product);
      
      int combinations = product / vectorLengths[l];
      int mult_length = product / mult_Vector[l];
      int n = 0;
      for (int m = 0; m < combinations; m++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < vectorLengths[l]; k++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < mult_length  && n < product; j++) {
            tmp[n] = ((IntegerVector)inputVectors[l])[k];
            n++;
          }
        }
      }
      
      output[l]= tmp;
      l++;
      break;
    }
    case STRSXP: {
      CharacterVector tmp(product);
      
      int combinations = product / vectorLengths[l];
      int mult_length = product / mult_Vector[l];
      int n = 0;
      for (int m = 0; m < combinations; m++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < vectorLengths[l]; k++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < mult_length && n < product; j++) {
            tmp[n] = ((CharacterVector)inputVectors[l])[k];
            n++;
          }
        }
      }
      
      output[l]= tmp;
      l++;
      break;
    }
    default: {
      stop("incompatible SEXP encountered; only accepts lists containing lists, REALSXPs, and INTSXPs");
    }
    }
  }
  output.attr("names") = col_names;
  DataFrame df(output);
  
  return df;
  
}
```